# Granite Widgets : Unable to append a new action item to welcome page at runtime

Tags: programming, development, vala

I am trying to add and remove action to welcome screen at run time on pressing Add and Delete buttons in Header Bar.

I am unable to append a new action item to welcome page at runtime.

check Code [here](http://pastebin.com/J02EJisJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check it currently, but this sounds like you *are* adding the widget and it simply doesn't show. When adding a new widget to `welcomeLayout`, running `welcomeLayout.show_all ()` *should* show the new widget(s). You might want to run this after adding a new item in `public void addAWelcomeButton ()`.

Comment: Yes, It works fine. Thnx